# Why does shift with an argument cause an infinite loop in this bash script?

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

I have the following `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while (( "$#" )); do

  case $1 in
    --foo)
      foo=$2
      ;;
    --bar | -b)
      bar=$2
      ;;
    *)
      echo "what?"
      ;;
  esac

  shift
  shift

done

echo $foo
echo $bar
```

If I run `./my_script.sh -b first --foo second --third` I get

```
what?
second
first
```

But if I change the two `shift` statements to a single `shift 2` I just get an infinite loop of `what?`s. What difference between `shift; shift` and `shift 2` causes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shift) documentation of `shift n`:

> If `n` is zero or greater than `$#`, the positional parameters are not changed.

So if `$#` is 1 and you execute `shift 2`, nothing happens but the return status will be non-zero, indicating failure.

Posix requires that the argument `n` be no greater than `$#`. If you fail to ensure that, the script might be terminated (if it is not interactive) or the `shift` command might terminate with a non-zero status. So even aside from this particular problem, portable code should not use `shift n` unless it is known that there are at least `n` arguments.